# IDEA Gives warning 'some variable always false'?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I wrote following code fragment with loop.But when Variable  'X' given always 'false' in IDEA , this line

`final boolean isCurrentDoseIsPeriodicOrEO = (CommonToolkit.INSTANCE.isPeriodicDosage(doseDetail) || X)`;

I need some explain it is not necessary put that or condition there.

```
    boolean isFirstDose = true;
    boolean isFirstDoseIsPeriodicOrWholePRNOrEoOrOneOff = false;

    for (final DDT: dd)
    {

      final boolean X=
        DosageToolkit.INSTANCE.hasEOTypeDosage(new DoseDetailMutableDTOToBaseDoseDetailAdapter(dd));
      final boolean isOneOffDose = CommonToolkit.INSTANCE.isOneOffDose(dd);

      if (dd.isWholeWhenNeeded() || X|| isOneOffDose)
      {
        if (isFirstDose)
        {
          isFirstDoseIsPeriodicOrWholePRNOrEoOrOneOff=true;
          isFirstDose = false;
        }

        continue;
      }

      final List<DIT> doseInstances =
        new ArrayList<DIT>(dd.getDoseInstances());
      Collections.sort(doseInstances, CommonToolkit.INSTANCE.getDoseInstanceComparator());

      final boolean isCurrentDoseIsPeriodicOrEO = (CommonToolkit.INSTANCE.isPeriodicDosage(doseDetail) || X);

      for (final DITdoseInstance : doseInstances)
          {
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Look, you verify `X` two times and both times is using `||` operator.

If `X` is true then first condition will be met and loop will continue to next iteration.

It means that when you verify `X` at `final boolean isCurrentDoseIsPeriodicOrEO = (CommonToolkit.INSTANCE.isPeriodicDosage(doseDetail) || X);` then it is always false because if it is true then execution cannot reach this point.

IDEA suggests you simplify to `final boolean isCurrentDoseIsPeriodicOrEO = (CommonToolkit.INSTANCE.isPeriodicDosage(doseDetail));`